# Why can't compose-compiler-1.2.0.pom be found?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Why am I getting this error when I set my compose_ui_version to 1.2.0?

```
compose_ui_version = '1.2.0'
```

```
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareDebugKotlinCompileTask'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose:compose-compiler:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.2.0/compose-compiler-1.2.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.2.0/compose-compiler-1.2.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.2.0/compose-compiler-1.2.0.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/androidx/compose/compose-compiler/1.2.0/compose-compiler-1.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

It seems it should be available in one of the major repositories.

Comment: Please give more details. How does your `build.gradle` look like? What are the `major repositories` that you mentioned?

Comment: I updated Gradle and the Android Gradle plugin and found that the name was changed for this library.  It originally looked for 'compose-compiler' and now it's named only 'compiler', so I think it was an issue with which name was expected based on the dependencies.